# Difference between 'debase' and 'degrade'

Tags: verbs, differences

What does *debase* mean? Is there any difference between the words *debase* and  *degrade*?

*Collins Dictionary* says this about [*debase*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/debase):

> To **debase** something means to reduce its value or quality. *[formal] Politicians have debased the meaning of the word 'freedom'.* [VERB noun] *'He said parliament and the process of democracy had been debased.* [VERB noun]

and this about [*degrade*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/degrade):

> Something that **degrades** someone causes people to have less respect for them.  *...the notion that pornography degrades women.* [VERB noun] *When I asked him if he had ever taken bribes he said he wouldn't degrade himself like that.* [VERB pronoun-reflexive]

So, according to these definitions, we degrade some*one* and we debase some*thing*. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

James Fernald, *English Synonyms and Antonyms*, twenty-first edition (1914) lists *debase* and *degrade* in a synonym group that also includes *abase*, *bring low*, *cast down*, *depress*, *discredit*, *disgrace*, *dishonor*, *humble*, *humiliate*, *lower*, *reduce*, and *sink*. Fernald offers this distinction between the two words:

> ***Debase*** applies to quality or character. The coinage is *debased* by excess of alloy; the man, by vice. ... ***Degrade*** may refer to either station or character. An officer is *degraded* by being reduced to the ranks [of common soldiers], *disgraced* by cowardice; vile practises *degrade*; drunkenness is a *degrading* vice. Misfortune or injustice may *abase* the good; nothing but their own ill-doing can *debase* or *disgrace* them.

Similarly, *Webster's Dictionary of Synonyms* (1942) identifies debase and degrade as members of a synonym group that also includes *abase*, *demean*, *humble*, and *humiliate*, and offers this commentary on the two words:

> **Abase, demean, debase, degrade, humble, humiliate** are synonymous when they denote to lower (one) in one's own estimation or in that of others. ... **Debase** emphasizes deterioration in value or quality it is more often used of things (as , to *debase* the currency), but when used of persons it commonly connotes weakening of moral standards or of the moral character; as, officeholders *debase* themselves by accepting bribes. "How books ... *debase* The many for the pleasure of those few" (*Wordsworth*). **Degrade** stresses a lowering in plane rather than in rank and often conveys a strong implication of the shamefulness of the condition to which the person (or group or thing) has been reduced. "That she and Charlotte, two spent old women, should be ... talking to each other of hatred, seemed unimaginably hideous and *degrading*" (*E. Wharton*) Often (esp. in **degradation**) it connotes actual degeneracy or corruption. "It was by that unscrupulous person's liquor her husband had been *degraded*" (Hardy).

Much like Webster's, S.I. Hayakawa, *Choose the Right Word: A Modern Guide to Synonyms* (1968) links *debase* and *degrade* to the words *abase*, *demean*, *disgrace*, *humble*, and *humiliate*:

> These words indicate the act of stripping someone of pride, self-respect, rank, or reputation. ... **Degrade** may or may not refer to a literal demotion: a sergeant *degraded* to the rank of private first class. More often the word suggests disgusting or immoral habits or behavior that destroys a person's character or publicly *disgraces* him: a fine mind *degraded* and dulled by dope addiction; accusations intended to *degrade* him and destroy his reputation. ...
>
> **Debase** suggests an action that reduces the intrinsic value of something: currency *debased* by inflationary measures; political discussion *debased* by an atmosphere of hysteria. As can be seen, *debase* may be more factual or descriptive than *degrade*, which suggests a more thorough but more subjective or moral sort of depredation.

I think that the last sentence in the Hayakawa excerpt is far more on point than any effort to impute a basic division in meaning that applies *debase* to things and *degrade* to people. *Debasement* is certainly a lowering, but it may be asserted at the end of a dispassionate analysis. *Degradation*, on the other hand, more often has a moral dimension, including a reaction of moral repugnance.

Still, I advise against treating these two words as if they were distinct in compass when properly used. In reality, the two words have a tremendous amount of overlap and even interchangeability—as do they and allied words such as *demean*, *discredit*, and *disgrace*—in everyday speech. The reference works that I've cited here do a nice job of identifying trends and tendencies in historical usage (and to some extent in contemporary usage), but they point to nuances, not to fundamental differences in meaning or usage.